# Desktop App Converter Microsoft Store validation errors

Tags: uwp, windows-10-desktop, appx, desktop-app-converter

I use the DesktopAppConverter via PowerShell to create the "appx" file format.

This is what I do:

```
DesktopAppConverter.exe -Installer C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\input\ -AppExecutable MPA.exe -Destination C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\output -PackageName "1005Mark" -AppId "MobilePayAlerts" -Publisher "CN=Verylong-ID-HERE" -Version 1.0.0.0 -Makeappx -Verbose -Sign
```

So this is the error I'm getting when uploading the appx file: *"Package acceptance validation error: The PublisherDisplayName element in the app manifest of 1005Mark.appx is Verylong-ID-HERE, which doesn't match your publisher display name: Mark."*

But If I change the `-Publisher` parameter to **Mark** I get the following error(s):

- Invalid package identity name: 1005Mark (expected:
  1005Mark.MobilePayAlerts)
- Invalid package family name: 1005Mark_x9f05h8vsrrp6 (expected:
  1005Mark.MobilePayAlerts_921pvy5st3vqc)
- Invalid package publisher name: CN=Mark (expected:
  CN=Verylong-ID-HERE)
- This package’s manifest (Package/Properties/DisplayName) uses a
  display name that you have not reserved: 1005Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the *PulisherDisplayName* element is set by the optional parameter `PackagePublisherDisplayName`, which is different from `Publisher`.

Can you try this command?:

> DesktopAppConverter.exe -Installer C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\input\ -AppExecutable MPA.exe -Destination C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\output -PackageName "1005Mark" -AppId "MobilePayAlerts" -Publisher "CN=Verylong-ID-HERE" -PackagePublisherDisplayName "Mark" -Version 1.0.0.0 -Makeappx -Verbose -Sign